# AJAX GET simple PHP Multiple variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need a simple way to retrieve multiple PHP variables into html divs. I searched a lot of posts but I can't found an answer.

I am looking for something like this:

go-to-index.php

```
<?php
    $name = 'Jonh';
    $phone = '123456789';
    $details = 'Detail about';
?>
```

index.php

```
<div class="name">Your Name is : <?php echo $name; ?></div>
<div class="phone">Your Phone Number is : <?php echo $phone; ?></div>
<div class="details">Your Details are : <?php echo $details; ?></div>
```

I want instead of echo to get them via AJAX Call.

What is the correct AJAX REQUEST syntax to do that?

**UPDATE**

My bad I do not noticed before but forgot to say I also need to load the calls one by one. I have too many requests and take a lot of time.

May the query .each() function should work like I want?

Comment: Make an AJAX request to `go-to-index.php` from `index.php`. The `go-to` page will need to output the content.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand what you say but I need a litle help. I don't know the correct syntax of code. May you can give me an example code. Thanks

Comment: There is a doc here on how to do it, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. It isn't a single line thing. You'll probably want to return a JSON object and then parse through it on the client to get your individual values....or you could just have the PHP build your 3 divs and then just inject that into your page..

Comment: Yes exaclty I want to return JSON object but I do not know how to do, I have already looked at the link you have send me. I will try to make the code myself but is so difficult.

Comment: Try out `echo json_encode(array("name"=> 'Jonh', 'phone' => '123456789', 'details' => 'Detail about'));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(Array(
    'name' => "John",
    'phone' => "1234567890",
    'details' => "Details about..."
));
```

Your HTML:

```
<div class="name">Your Name is : <span class="name_value"></span></div>
<div class="phone">Your Phone Number is : <span class="phone_value"></span></div>
<div class="details">Your Details are : <span class="details_value"></span></div>
```

Your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('user-info.php',function(data){
        $(".name_value").html(data.name);
        $(".phone_value").html(data.phone);
        $(".details_value").html(data.details);
    });
});
```

Note: you'll set the `user-info.php` string to the URL (relative or absolute) of your PHP script that grabs the user info.

Comment: Working perfect, but I want to do something like and is not working.  `$content = "THIS IS A GOOD QUESTION"

if(preg_match('[QUESTION]', $content)) { 

$conform = "Found";
}else{
$conform = "Not Found";
}

echo json_encode(Array(
    'name' => $conform,
    'phone' => "1234567890",
    'details' => "Details about..."
));`

Comment: You want their name to be "Found" or "Not Found"?? How about we add the indicator of if it's a question into its own field.. Here's that: `$is_question = ( stripos( $content, 'question' ) ? 1 : 0 ); echo json_encode( Array( 'name' => "John", 'phone' => "1234567890", 'details' => "Details about...", 'is_question' => $is_question ) );`

Comment: Hello, do you know how can I make it to load the requests one by one and not waiting for all ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a PHP script that will output JSON containing the values you want, and you need a Javascript handler to ask for that data and do something when it gets it. Here's an example:

```
# File: go-to-index.php
<?php

$name = 'Jonh';
$phone = '123456789';
$details = 'Detail about';

echo json_encode(
    [
        'name' => $name,
        'phone' => $phone,
        'details' => $details
    ]
);
```

Then your HTML page:

```
<!-- File: index.php -->
<div class="name">Your Name is : <span class="container"></span></div>
<div class="phone">Your Phone Number is : <span class="container"></span></div>
<div class="details">Your Details are : <span class="container"></span></div>

<button class="loadMe" type="button">Click here to make things work</button>
```

And finally your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loadMe').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            // Path to your backend handler script
            url: 'go-to-index.php';
            // Tell jQuery that you expect JSON response
            dataType: 'json',
            // Define what should happen once the data is received
            success: function (result) {
                $('.name .container').html(result.name);
                $('.phone .container').html(result.phone);
                $('.details .container').html(result.details);
            },
            // Handle errors in retrieving the data
            error: function (result) {
                alert('Your AJAX request didn\'t work. Debug time!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You can do this on any event - the button was just an example. You can also use plain Javascript or any other library, just used jQuery since you tagged it in your question.